# Background of MainCamera (Unity C#)

Tags: unity-game-engine

I writing simple runner game

I have Main Camera and have Image. I want to set this Image as Main Camera background.

Screen of my Main Camera[image: Main Camera]

Comment: You may just attach the image, resize i so it is bigger than camera view, and set is as bottom layer (behind everything else). Camera in unity doesn't have any built-in background functionality. Also if you move camera, you may want to make the background a child of camera or attach the script that will reposition the background according to camera movement.

Comment: Right, as Luka explains there is **no such thing as a 'background' in Unity**.  It's just an image like any other.  If you happen to put it "at the back", it will be your background. ( @ŁukaszMotyczka -- do you know, can you even use a skybox in Unity 2D ???)

Comment: Not sure, never tried. I used skybox in 3d project. But for 2d projects I just put a sprite background.

Answer (score 66, accepted):

** **Edit 2020**

Unity now has a simple way to do this, in **Unity 2018.4+**.

Follow these few steps to add texture as a camera background:

1. Create a new **Canvas** that would hold your image.
2. In that canvas, on *Canvas component* set:

   - **Render Mode** to **Screen Space - Camera**.
   - **Render Camera** to your main camera (drag&drop).
   - **Plane Distance** are the units, at which the background would render.
3. Right-click on the newly created canvas and create an **Image** inside of it.
4. On the newly created image on *Image component*:

   - Set **Source Image** to your desired background sprite.
5. Stretch your image to the full screen size. You can do this as follows: in the **Rect Transform** of that image, there is a *gray square in it with some arrows, and lines (saying **stretch** on top and left side)*, click it, a window with multiple squares would open, hold down the **Alt** and click the most **bottom-right** square.

Now you should have a tecture as camera background!

---

** **old Unity**

You can make it using a **Skybox**, or you can use a **GUI Texture**.

***Here's how I made it some time before:***

1. Create a new camera (GameObject -> Create Other -> Camera), and name it "Background Camera".
2. Create a new GUI Texture (GameObject -> Create Other -> GUI Texture), and name it "Background Image".
3. Click the "Layer" dropdown menu in the Background Image's inspector pane, and select "Add Layer".
4. In the next free "User Layer" slot, create a new layer name called "Background Image". This will be directly under the layer named "Terrain" if you haven't yet added any others.
5. Select your Background Image in the hierarchy, and give it the desired texture, and set the x, y, width and height under "Pixel Inset" so that it fills the screen appropriately.
6. Near the top of the inspector window, Use the layer dropdown menu to assign your "Background Image" layer that you defined earlier to this gameobject.

***Now select your Background Camera in the hierarchy, and adjust these settings in the inspector:***

7. Un-Check Flare Layer and Audio Listener (but leave GUILayer enabled)
8. Set Clear Flags to Solid Color
9. Set Depth to -1
10. Set Culling Mask, first to "Nothing", and then to "Background Image"

***Now Select you other (main) camera, and in the inspector:***

11. Set its Clear Flags to "Depth Only"
12. Click its culling mask setting, and un-check "Background Image". This should result in the culling mask displaying as "Mixed ..."

*Voila, this should give you your GUI Texture rendered by your background camera, behind everything else rendered by your main camera. And for any other additional cameras (eg, other camera angles) that you want to use, just repeat the last two steps on them.*

Comment: I have Unity 5  and don't see GUI Texture(

Comment: Yes, GUI Texture is deprecated in this version of Unity, try to use **UI -> Image** instead, I can't check if this works for now

Comment: Thought Unity was Gold... but so many WEIRD... Where to put Create Canvas? In Hierarchy, in Resources? Learning Unity is WEIRD. Need some direction. Thx!

Comment: Is there a way to make it so the image follows the player a little bit behind, like a parallax or something? Mainly just a way to make the player feel like they are moving/speeding up

Comment: I was searching that info for 3 days... Thank you so much!

Answer (score 28):

that other answer seems so out of date. I thought I'd share something newer. Just simply:

- Right click your Main Camera, select **UI -> Image.**
- Select your image and on the little box in Rect Transform where it says *"stretch"* and *"stretch"*, click on that box. Now a menu will appear with a bunch of more boxes. Hold **ALT** and select the box furthest **Down Right **. This is the box with the blue arrows pointing at all directions.

*Now you have fit your image to your canvas. In addition to this, you will need to fit your canvas to your camera.*

- **Select your canvas**. Within the Canvas' inspector, look for a component called *Canvas*. Change the Render Mode to **Screen Space - Camera**. Now it will ask you for a camera at the *Render Camera box*. Simply drag your Main Camera to Render Camera and voila, you have now a screen filled background **without** having 2 cameras lmao :)

**Edit:**  Do not forget to turn off Raycasting for both the image and the canvas!

Comment: Oh thanks! I was looking for a an updated version because every comment was talking about old versions here and unity forum. This answer should go up!

Comment: I don't see a little box "stretch" and "stretch". Please change to "grey colored rectangle"

Comment: "Create image inside it" - Do you mean, right click, create, UI, Image? Details are important. The ins and outs of this Unity and the scripts in C# are very bizarre and not like any API I've used. I used many, Java, Flash/AS3, throughout over a decade and nothing is doing what is expected. I guess the NOOBS that started with this as a first glimpse into the development industry it makes sense, but the old guys it's bizarre.

Answer (score 2):

Unity comes with a skybox functionality which you could use to create a background. It may take some reshaping but you should be able to reach the desired effect with the tutorial [here](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/HOWTO-UseSkybox.html).

Answer (score 0):

**STEPS:**

- Make a new *Canvas*.
- In that canvas, on Canvas component set **Render Mode** to *Screen Space - Camera*.
- Render Camera to your main camera (*drag&drop*),Plane Distance are the units, at which the background would render.
- Right-click on the newly created canvas and **create an Image** inside of it.
- Set **Source Image**(drag&drop) to your desired background sprite.
- *Stretch your image* to the full screen size.
- You can do this as follows: in the **Rect Transform** of that image, there is a **gray square** in it with some arrows, and lines (saying stretch on top and left side), click it, a window with multiple squares would open, **hold down the Alt** and **click the most bottom-right square**.

Answer (score 0):

For Users using URP Camera, setting Background is easy.

In URP we have two types of cameras Base And Overlay. Its the first option of Camera Component called **RENDER TYPE**

1. Set your MainCamera as Base Camera and culling mask to nothing.
2. Create two more cameras as Overlays.
3. 1 of them is going to render the whole game and the other one is
   going to render the background. Suppose I name them RenderGame &
   RenderBackground.
4. For background create separate CANVAS with screenSpace - Camera. and
   put the Overlay camera which is going to render the background in
   it. and set its layer as "Background Layer"
5. create and assign a separate layer for canvas containing background.
6. For RenderGame camera set culling mask to everything and then
   deselect "Background Layer".
7. For RenderBackground set culling mask to only "Background Layer".
8. And last In mainCamera There is the option called Stack under which
   first put  RenderBackground and then RenderGame. **Order is
   Important**

[For help you can refer to Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jWu4U.png)